# Bogus error for a Form_for! Has this happened to anyone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

My Form..

```
<%= form_for @wysiwyg, :url => admin_wysiwyg_path do |f| %>
<%= f.ckeditor_textarea(:content, :width => '100%', :height => '200px') %>
<%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

Right? Makes sense, I'm not going crazy, right?

Error:

```
compile error
default/app/views/admin/wysiwygs/new.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...=> admin_wysiwyg_path do |f| ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...
```

Routes:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :wysiwygs
```

This is inside of a Spree App using CkEditor

Comment: do you run this on rails 3 or on rails 2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This obscenely written form_for works :

```
<% form_for(@wysiwyg, :url => admin_wysiwygs_url, :html => { :method => :put}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.ckeditor_textarea(:content, :width => '100%', :height => '200px') %>
  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like parenthesizing the call to form_for got rid of the automatic parentheses addition that was causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error shows you where the extra parentheses is. It seems that it is getting added by the erb syntax.

```
                             #right here
=> admin_wysiwyg_path do |f| ).to_s)
```

I use haml instead of erb, partly for this reason. However, you may be able to fix this by parenthesizing your call to form_for. Something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@wysiwyg, :url => admin_wysiwyg_path) do |f| %>
<%= f.ckeditor_textarea(:content, :width => '100%', :height => '200px') %>
<%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hmm very strange. I see what you're saying but the code I pasted above is literally the only code I have there.

Comment: And 2nd, why would anyone want to stringify their url? :D

Comment: I see. It seems like you have an erb syntax error then. Try putting parentheses around the call to form_for. I'll edit my answer.